# Find filtered record with Ember.js and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I'm trying to add a "where" filter in my Rails backend doing so :

```
  def index
    @label = Label
    if params[:filter].present?
      @label =  @label.where(uid: params[:filter])
    end

    @label = @label.all

    render json: @label
  end
```

The problem is that I get this SQL request:

```
  Label Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "uid"."uid" = 'VALUE'
```

And **"uid"."uid"** throws an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: uid.uid: SELECT "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "uid"."uid" = 'VALUE'):
```

app/controllers/labels_controller.rb:13:in `index'

**EDIT**

Here my label schema:

```
  create_table "labels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "uid",        null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Do you know why it doens't use **"labels"."uid"** ?

Comment: Do you have `uid` column in `Label model`. I'm sure it would be id instead.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to filter by uid (user id) sent by my frontend. I don't have user table anymore. My users are in a different database.

Comment: I believe you could not execute above query in rails console as well ...

Comment: Isn't it possible to select records by attributes values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't explain why it didn't work, but here my solution :

```
  def index
    @label = Label

    if params[:filter].present?
      @label = @label.where("uid = ?", params[:filter][:uid])
    end

    @label = @label.all

    render json: @label
  end
```